# Prefix routing and plugins in CAKEPHP 1.2/1.3

Tags: plugins, routes, cakephp-1.3, prefix, cakephp-1.2

Does anybody have examples of setting up the `routes.php` table when using plugins and prefix routing in CakePHP

e.g.

A shops controller, using the `manage` prefix to access certain management functions for the seller.

So `/manage/shops/edit` maps to `manage_edit` in `shops_controller.php`

and then placing this in  `/plugins/shops`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `core.php` there is a configuration value called: `Routing.prefixes` you need to set the **manage** prefix there:

`Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('admin', 'manage'));`

Now all calls to URLs like */manage/controllerName/actionName* will go to: `controllerName::manage_actionName`

and all calls to URLs like */admin/controllerName/actionName* will go to: 
`controllerName::admin_actionName`

For plugin routing in the `routes.php` file:

```
Router::connect('/shops/edit', array('plugin' => 'pluginName', 'controller' => 'shops', 'action' => 'edit'));
```

This is all that is needed.